# export matplotlib contour lines to text file

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I am trying to export the contour lines from matplotlib to a text file. From the information here, I was able to create a MWE, that nearly works.

```
def export_contours(fname, cn):
    with open(fname, 'w') as fp:
        # for each contour line
        for v, cc in zip(cn.cvalues, cn.collections):
            if len(cc.get_paths()) == 0:
                continue
            p = cc.get_paths()[0]
            n = np.size(p.vertices, 0)
            contour = np.hstack([p.vertices, np.ones((n,1))*v])
            np.savetxt(fp, contour, comments='# ',delimiter=',', newline='\n' )
            fp.write('\n')
            
            
def f(x,y):
    return x**2 + y**2

XX,YY = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 1,100), np.linspace(-1, 1, 50))
ZZ = f(np.ravel(XX)[:,None], np.ravel(YY)[:,None]).reshape(XX.shape)
plt.clf()
cn = plt.contour(XX,YY,ZZ)       
            
export_contours('./contour.txt',cn)
```

Loading this data again in `pgfplots`, the outer rings seem to be missing.
I can also see, that for the level 1.75, there are only 10 entries in the text file.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
        \addplot3[contour prepared] table[x index=0, y index=1, z index=2, col sep=comma,] {data/gd_peak_contour.txt};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Anybody an idea what the problem could be?